# how do I subtract -1 if a specific char is not found within a string

Tags: java, string, char

I need some hints on how to program this, this method is for a hangman game `guessCh` is the letter user has guessed while `secretCh` is the letters in the secret word, they come from a `while() loop` one at a time. But what I need is instead of just `if (guessCh != secretCh)` wich don´t work cause the secret word consist of severall letters so it will subtract points from all those letters within the secret word, that it should not subtract from. Only if the `guessCh` char is not found in any of the `secretCh` letters / or within the secret word should it subtract -1.

I seem to be stuck on this, I know it´s simple... but throw me a bone. I´ve already spent to much time on this.

```
private void nTurns(char guessCh, char secretCh) {
    //Create an array that stores already used letters
    if (guessCh != secretCh) {
        nTurnsLeft--;
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to subtract 1. Subtracting -1 is the same as adding 1. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The String object already has this functionality built in.

All you really need is something like this:

```
if(secretStr.indexOf(guessCh) < 0) nTurnsLeft--;
```

indexOf returns the index of the location of the char guessCh inside the String secretStr. If guessCh is not found, then indexOf returns -1;

Comment: yes... I haven´t thought of using indexOf() in that context, but works great... with little code aswell. Time to beat myself for not thinking of it b4.

Answer (score 4):

You could do an ArrayList of the characters found in your secret.
Then use  `.contains(Char c)` method from the ArrayList

An Example:

```
ArrayList<Char> secret = new ArrayList<Char>();
secret.add('w');
secret.add('o');
secret.add('r');
secret.add('l');
secret.add('d');

if(secret.contains(new Char('x')) {
    System.out.println("Found");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not Found");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be homework, so gtgaxiola's answer could be something the teacher doesn't want to see. Here is how to implement the equivalent of .contains() on a normal array of chars so you don't have to change too much in your current code.

```
    char[] secretCh = new char[]{'s', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't'};
    char guessCh = 'e';

    boolean found = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < secretCh.length; i++) { // loop through each character in the secretCh array
        if (secretCh[i] == guessCh) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found)
        System.out.println("guessCh is a letter in the secret word.");
```